# Can you apply an apostrophe to any word?

Tags: apostrophe

If I were to say `The skill is` could I say it as `The skill's`? Or would this not work? Also, if it does work, could I apply to it to any word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the functions of the apostrophe is as a *written* designation of missing letters. While it would probably be understood by native speakers that the word *is* is being shortened if you said, "The skill's hard to acquire," that's not really an accepted use of an apostrophe in written English. If you were to write dialogue, though, I think it would pass.

We do that in **speech** all the time for the verb *is* or *has* and other constructions that are not written out.

> - The dog's in the neighbor's yard again! (dog is)
> - The game's already started. (game has)

Could you apply it to any word? No more than you can use *is* or *has* after every word and have it make sense.

Comment: So actually using an apostrophe in the above phrase is more colloquial?

Comment: In speech, yes, it's colloquial.

Comment: No, it's not. In speech there are no apostrophes; they're only for writing, so using an apostrophe is not colloquial, because "colloquial" means spoken dialog, not writing. Contractions occur in speech and they're colloquial; but apostrophes have nothing to do with the language. They're used as a crutch for the written language, to indicate a few changes in words forced by language change. The use of apostrophe for possessives, however, is simply silly, since it adds nothing useful and is mostly used wrong.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Saying *colloquial* can only apply to speech is a prime example of the etymological fallacy.

Comment: @JohnLawler - I agree there are no apostrophes in speech; I thought that was clear from my first sentence. And I stipulated that it could be used to *record dialogue*. So I'm not sure why you are correcting me, as I believe we're on the same page about that. But, as I have your attention, is there never writing that is colloquial, that is, that attempts to affect a conversational tone?

Comment: The key word is "attempts". Anything that refers to a goal of the writer is automatically not part of language but of art, and it can only attempt to reproduce speech, never to actually achieve it. Written words are silent, as Socrates pointed out. Punctuation, as something unique to writing, can't be colloquial because it is standardized.